# pandas groupby column then create two other columns based on third column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to group a dataframe by a column and get the total "Approved" or "Not Approved" values based on this grouping, but with no success.

Example:

```
PlaceTest | Approved    
       21 |        1    
       21 |        0    
       22 |        1    
       22 |        0
```

My desired output:

```
PlaceTest | Approved | NotApproved    
       21 |        1 |           1    
       22 |        1 |           1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given

```
>>> df
   PlaceTest  Approved
0         21         1
1         21         0
2         22         1
3         22         0
```

you can issue

```
>>> df.assign(NotApproved=1 - df['Approved']).groupby('PlaceTest').sum().reset_index()
   PlaceTest  Approved  NotApproved
0         21         1            1
1         22         1            1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this slightly different way, which is two line process though.

```
$ df
   Approved  PlaceTest
0         1         21
1         0         21
2         1         22
3         0         22
```

First `groupby` and `sum` with a new column:

```
$ df['Not Approved'] = df.groupby('PlaceTest')['Approved'].sum()
```

lastly again `groupby` with `fillna`

```
$ df = df.groupby('PlaceTest')['Approved', 'Not Approved'].sum().fillna("1").reset_index()

$ df
   PlaceTest  Approved Not Approved
0         21         1            1
1         22         1            1
```

**Note :** Its working with pandas version `0.21.0`.

For version greater than `0.21.0` should use as follows for the above use case:

```
>>> df.groupby('PlaceTest')['Approved', 'Not Approved'].max().fillna("1").reset_index()
   PlaceTest  Approved Not Approved
0         21         1            1
1         22         1            1
```

Comment: When copy-pasting your code I get only `0.0` in the "Not Approved" column.

Comment: Is that really ? i'm on  linux python shell 3.6 with pandas version `0.21.0`

Comment: Please see https://pastebin.com/Jn7R7kFF, anyways +1 to your nice solution.

Comment: @timgeb, you are right i just tested with pandas version `0.23.3` with python 3.7 and it results same as your https://pastebin.com/YaGddBZC   , but works with `0.21.0`

Comment: It looks like a bug while using with sum() following fillna it do not action on it

Comment: I think the problem is the line `df['Not Approved'] = df.groupby('PlaceTest')['Approved'].sum()` setting the column "Not Approved" to all NaN values because the `Series` on the right hand side of the `=` does not match the row index of the original `df`.

Comment: Hmm, but it works correctly on the lower pandas version :) if you try that with `0.21.0`, i'm planning to riase a new question on this , lets see if there is any major difference/shift  for this cause.