# Pandas returns different result using fillna() with sum() over the greater versions than 0.21.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

While going through a Question over SO and simulation an answer i found a weird behaviour between Pandas version's `0.21.0`

While using `fillna` along with `sum()` for a columns it works as desired However, it results `0.0` above version `0.21.0`.

**DataFrame Structure:**

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'PlaceTest':[21,21,22,22], 'Approved':[1,0,1,0]})
>>> df
   PlaceTest  Approved
0         21         1
1         21         0
2         22         1
3         22         0
```

Creating New column with `groupby`  while using `sum()` ..

```
>>> df['Not Approved'] = df.groupby('PlaceTest')['Approved'].sum()
>>> df
   PlaceTest  Approved  Not Approved
0         21         1           NaN
1         21         0           NaN
2         22         1           NaN
3         22         0           NaN
```

Now, While using version `0.21.0` it get the desired result as follows:

```
>>> df = df.groupby('PlaceTest')['Approved', 'Not Approved'].sum().fillna("1").reset_index()

>>> df
   PlaceTest  Approved Not Approved
0         21         1            1
1         22         1            1
```

However, it turns no result while using same approach with version `0.23.3` .

```
>>> df.groupby('PlaceTest')['Approved', 'Not Approved'].sum().fillna("1").reset_index()
   PlaceTest  Approved  Not Approved
0         21         1           0.0
1         22         1           0.0
```

Is there any change of functionality over the greater version of pandas while using `sum()` along with `fillna` method?

Would appreciate any expert comments on this, it might be there but seems out of my head at the moment.

Reference question [goes here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53570890/pandas-groupby-column-then-create-two-other-columns-based-on-third-column/53572336?noredirect=1#comment94009874_53572336)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [What's New in Pandas v0.22.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0220-api-breaking) (my emphasis):

> Pandas 0.22.0 changes the handling of empty and all-NA sums and products. The summary is that
>
> - **The sum of an empty or all-NA Series is now 0**
> - The product of an empty or all-NA Series is now 1
>
> Some background: In pandas 0.21, we fixed a long-standing inconsistency in the return value of all-NA series depending on whether or not bottleneck was installed. See [Sum/Prod of all-NaN or empty Series/DataFrames is now consistently NaN](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0210-api-breaking-bottleneck). At the same time, we changed the sum and prod of an empty Series to also be NaN. **In v0.21.0 the sum of an empty or all-NA Series was NaN**.

So in v.0.22.0:

```
In [16]: df.groupby('PlaceTest')['Approved', 'Not Approved'].sum()
Out[16]: 
           Approved  Not Approved
PlaceTest                        
21                1           0.0
22                1           0.0
```

whereas, in v0.21.0:

```
In [16]: df.groupby('PlaceTest')['Approved', 'Not Approved'].sum()
Out[16]: 
           Approved  Not Approved
PlaceTest                        
21                1           NaN
22                1           NaN
```

Thus, in the former case `fillna("1")` does nothing since there are no NaNs to be filled.